# Combining Multi-Line text columns together in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, spreadsheet, sublimetext

Lets say I have 2 columns with a billion lines in each here's how they begin:

**Column 1**

```
I said
She said
it said
```

**Column 2**

```
you're amazing
he's awesome
enough already
```

I've tried highlighting column 1 and splitting it into lines CTRL+L but then how would I combine column 2's lines to each of colum 1's lines properly to make 1 legible column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you want to do but if I do then...

Use multiple selections like this:

[image: Animated Gif]

Hope this helps and is in fact what you want to do. :)

Comment: Haha that's awesome, final question... Did you use a service or did you manually record a video and convert it to make that gif?

Comment: I used a useful Linux screen record program called [SimpleScreenRecorder](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/). It's really simple and quick to use. Most usefully it has a select window feature, so that you can just click on the application you want to record, hit the start record button or hotkey and go. If my animated gif answers your question will you +1 and accept my answer please. Cheers.