# Sublime text - Copy multiple selection to end of line

Tags: replace, sublimetext3, editor, find-replace

In sublime 3.2.2 I need to copy and paste multiple selection to end of each line. What I did was Edit>replace, enter find term using regex, press `alt+enter`, press `Ctrl +c`, press key `end`, press `Ctrl+v`. Now what happens is like below,

1.a (a) here
2. a (b) here

regex find is `\(\w\)`

I get like,

1.a (a) here
(a)
(b)
2. a (b) here
(a)
(b)

Insted of

1.a (a) here(a)
2. a (b) here(b)

I tried for small number of lines it worked, But when having five thousands like it give results as not desired. Same problem in my visual studio code also.

Comment: This answer shows how to do it quickly with multiple selections on a small number of lines but not with 1000s: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25145301/2102457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a regex search and replace in Sublime, assuming that you'll only have at most one match per line. Select **`Find → Replace…`**, make sure the Regex (`*`) button is selected, and enter (per your example) `(\(\w\))(.*)` in the Search field. This creates two capture groups - the desired letter surrounded by parens, and the rest of the line after the close paren.

In the Replace field, put `\1\2\1`. Hit Replace All (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) and you should be good to go.

---

Alternatively, you can try this: Use your original regex and Find All,  hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy, then <kbd>End</kbd>. Then, before you paste, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) to split the selection into lines. Now you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and it should paste how you want.

Comment: @JustineChacko what platform are you on?

Comment: I am on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: @JustineChacko Ah, I tested this on Windows. There are some minor differences in behavior between platforms, although by and large the keyboard shortcuts are the same between Windows and Linux.